# mongodb underscore wildcard search

Tags: mongodb, search, wildcard

I am a newbie to mongodb. I just want to know what is the Mongodb equivalent operator for mysql _ for wildcard search. For example in mysql if want to search a phone number column in the format of 123 456 7890 we can search like '**_ _** ____'. How do we search it in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in MySql you might have a query with a wildcard like this:

`mysql> SELECT * FROM pets WHERE name LIKE '_____';`

In Mongo, you can use [regex syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), like:
`db.pets.find( { name: { $regex: /[a-zA-Z]{5}/ } } );`

If you can write regex for what you want, then you can query in this way.

There are some expressions for things like phone numbers here: http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: but it gives me 5 or more characters much. what if I want exactly 5 characters to be matched

Comment: @sureshsgpm you'd just need to write the regular expression to match what you want. In this case, to match on 5 only, you could do something like this: /^.{5}$/ instead. You'd need to just look up how to write some regex.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, would you mind clicking the accept button next to it?